# Error while migrating in django

Tags: python, django

I'm sorry, I don't think the title of my question is comprehensible as I'm absolutely a noob trying to understand django after LPTHW. Anyway, I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-or-mariadb-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04) in setting up Django to use MariaDB. But unfortunately when I run `python manage.py migrate` I get humongous block of error message. Here's the block:

```
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (mysql.W002) MySQL Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'
    HINT: MySQL's Strict Mode fixes many data integrity problems in MySQL, such as data truncation upon insertion, by escalating warnings into errors. It is strongly recommended you activate it. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 412, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 375, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 276, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'django_content_type' already exists")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 91, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 312, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 133, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 412, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 375, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 276, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'django_content_type' already exists")
```

Expecting another command to work after that error, I ran

`python manage.py createsuperuser` which returned me another block of error:

```
You have 15 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 412, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 375, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 276, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'myproject.auth_user' doesn't exist")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 59, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 93, in handle
    default_username = get_default_username()
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 136, in get_default_username
    auth_app.User._default_manager.get(username=default_username)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 393, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1183, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1061, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 412, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 375, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/noob/Documents/projects/python/django/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 276, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'myproject.auth_user' doesn't exist")
```

Could you help me solve this?

Comment: There is an issue with the order your migrations were ran. order or migrations in important.

Comment: Not sure about the `Strict Mode` bit (I don't use MySQL myself), but I notice that the tutorial you are following is from 2015.  Wouldn't be surprised if there are configuration issues.  The two other stack traces you posted are completely what I would expect to happen if the migration was not run.  The tables have not been set up so you can't run those commands that rely on them.